# Django FloatField does render as input[type=number] even with localize=true

Tags: jquery, python, django, html

I am clueless about this. As far as documentation goes, django should render a FloatField as input[type="text"], when field.localize = True

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#floatfield

But in my case it is still rendered as input[type=number] - did I miss something?

The main problem with that is, that I have localized number representation and with type=number I get issues with retrieving the value.

Anyone can give me a hint, why django refuses to use type="text" when field.localize=true?

Thank you very much

Comment: You have migrated after updating the FloatField (assuming you might have update it later on)?

Comment: This is actuall a running software I have adopted to maintain - so yes, everything should be migrated, migration files also look valid and the html output also looks like a FloatField. The localize is set by iterating over all fields in ModelForm - which is executed - so localize IS set if field-class = 'FloatField' (i've validated by additionally setting a custom attr at the same time, which gets outputted)